# ThreeJS Upload multiple textures for .obj

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, blender

So I'm trying to upload a .obj file that also has multiple .png and .jpg files that are it's textures. The problem is I'm not sure how to even handle all these textures when they are uploaded.

Heres my code so far:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load(obj_path, function (obj) {

  model = obj;
  modelWithTextures = true;


  model.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;

  } );

  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
  var i;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    file = files[i];
    console.log('Texture Files:' + files[i].name);
    var texture = textureLoader.load(files[i].name);
  }
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  setCamera(model);
  setSmooth(model);

  model.position.set(0, 0, 0);

  setBoundBox(model);
  setPolarGrid(model);
  setGrid(model);
  setAxis(model);

  scaleUp(model);
  scaleDown(model);

  fixRotation(model);
  resetRotation(model);

  selectedObject = model;
  outlinePass.selectedObjects = [selectedObject];
  outlinePass.enabled = false;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  scene.add(model);
});
```

As you can see I'm using the textureLoader but just not sure what to do.

I'm very new to threeJS and 3d models.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your OBJ asset have a corresponding MTL file?

Comment: No it is a OBJ without an MTL file. I was told by anoterh developers that I needed to manually add these textures.

Comment: Can you please first ensure whether your OBJ file has texture coordinates or not?

Comment: Yes, my obj files does have texture coordinates and also has several png files that is it's textures.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you probably won't see very much, because you render the scene before you add the model to the scene. You should render the scene after you did any changes (unless you have a render loop with `requestAnimationFrame`). Loading textures also is asynchronous. Use the callback of the `.load` method to better react when things are finished loading, e.g. trigger `render()`.

I would load the textures within `model.traverse()` callback. But you have to determine which texture belongs to which mesh. This depends on how your data is structured.

```js
var files = ['mesh1_tex.jpg', 'mesh2_tex.jpg'];

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, -100); // depends on the size and location of your loaded model

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

loader.load(obj_path, function ( model ) {

  model.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
    
      // here you have to find a way how to choose the correct texture for the mesh
      // the following is just an example, how it could be done, but it depends on your data
      const file = files.find( f => f === child.name + '_tex.jpg');
      if (!file) {
        console.warn(`Couldn't find texture file.`);
        return;
      }
      
      textureLoader.load(file, ( texture ) => {
      
        child.material.map = texture;
        child.material.needsupdate = true;
        
        render(); // only if there is no render loop
      
      });
    
    }

  } );
  
  scene.add( model );
  
  camera.lookAt( model ); // depends on the location of your loaded model
  
  render(); // only if there is no render loop
  
});

function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  
}
```

*Disclaimer: I just wrote down this code without testing.*